# Synchronisation issue

Tags: error, network, qfield, qfield-cloud, permissionerror

I try to synchronise my project with QFieldCloud, but a network error occurs

> [QF/permission_denied_plan_insufficient] Permission denied because the useraccount’s plan is insufficient].

It worked well at my last attempt.
I had no error during the packaging.

Comment: I also am receiving this error. I am only using 5MB out of my free 100MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce you're project size under 100MB. That is the limit for free account.